# Multiple queries saves on desktop - Spool issue - SQL Developer

Tags: spool

My goal is to launch 3 queries simultaneously and save the outputs in 3 csv files on my desktop. Then, I link Power BI to those 3 results.

FI, the queries launched separately work well. For example, this works perfectly and I get my csv file saved on my desktop:

SPOOL "C:...";
SELECT /*csv*/
Query #1

However, when I stack the 3 queries one after the other, I have a "SQL command not properly ended" message:

SPOOL "C:...";
SELECT /*csv*/
Query #1

SPOOL "C:...";
SELECT /*csv*/
Query #2

SPOOL "C:...";
SELECT /*csv*/
Query #3

What should I change?

Thanks a lot!